# unable to install vlc-nox

Tags: vlc

I cannot install vlc-nox.

I am using the following commands:

```
sudo -i
apt-get clean
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
apt-get install vlc vlc-nox
```

And I obtain:

```
root@Nt08:~# apt-get install vlc vlc-nox
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package vlc-nox
root@Nt08:~#
```

I also removed and reinstall vlc but again I get the same: Unable to locate package vlc-nox.

Any help will be very valuable!
Thank you!

Comment: which ubuntu version?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 17.10

Comment: if your plan is to run vlc without gui you it can be run in a headless server `vlc -I http --http-port 8888 --http-password 12345` then access it with `http://localhost:8888`

Comment: @ptetteh227 Thank you for the suggestion, I'll keep it in mind.

Answer (score 0):

You may download `.deb` package from this source: [vlc-nox | pkgs.org](https://pkgs.org/download/vlc-nox)

Supported releases:

- Ubuntu 17.04 (Zesty Zapus)
- Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (Xenial Xerus)
- Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (Trusty Tahr)
- Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (Precise Pangolin)

Answer (score 0):

In my 16.04 LTS system, `vlc-nox` is installed from the repository `universe`.

```
$ apt-cache policy vlc-nox
vlc-nox:
  Installerad: 2.2.2-5ubuntu0.16.04.4
  Kandidat:    2.2.2-5ubuntu0.16.04.4
  Versionstabell:
 *** 2.2.2-5ubuntu0.16.04.4 500
        500 http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe i386 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.2.2-5 500
        500 http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe i386 Packages
```

- Please check that you have enabled the repository `universe`.
- Things may be different in other versions, so if you have enabled the repository `universe`, and still cannot find `vlc-nox`, it is probably not available for your version of Ubuntu.

Edit in response to your comment:

I have a test system with Ubuntu 17.10. Only `vlc` is available via the repository `universe`, but not `vlc-nox`. Also [answer about separate deb packages](https://askubuntu.com/a/1028736/737448) indicates that there is no such package for your version of Ubuntu.

Comment: @lookingforanswers, Which version of Ubuntu are you running?

Comment: I am using 17.10.

Comment: @lookingforanswers, Sorry, in 17.10 only the package `vlc` is available via the repository universe, but not `vlc-nox`.

Comment: Thank you for your response. In that case the conclusion is that vlc-nox cannot operate in ubuntu 17.10.

Comment: @lookingforanswers, There are alternatives (to play music without a graphical user interface). If you tell us how you intended to use `vlc-nox`, I think we can help you get something that works.

Comment: @lookingforanswers, Did you solve your problem, or do you still look for help? If you solved the problem, please share your solution, otherwise, please tell us how you intended to use `vlc-nox` (otherwise we don't know how to help).

Comment: @ sudodus Thank you for willing to help. I haven't solved my problem, I still get an error when I am trying to run this code  (which I cannot change by the way). So, I'll develop another program without vlc-nox.

Comment: @lookingforanswers, Good luck :-)

Answer (score 0):

Vlc is now packaged differently, there is no longer a vlc-nox package. The various vlc binaries are in the vlc-bin package.